# Storing employee attendance log data to Database using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, database-design

I'm developing Biometric Attendance System using [ZKTeco Standalone SDK and their Demo using VB.NET](http://www.zkteco.eu/index.php/downloads/software-downloads) and TFT (Thin-film Transistor) device.

What I've done so far:

1. Employee Registration
2. Employee Finger Print Scanning and Registration

Now when every registered employee places his/her finger on the device, the device stores what is called Attendance Log.

And later the Attendance Logs should be downloaded from the device to ListView, and then Saved to the EmployeeAttendance Table.

EmployeeAttendance Table Structure

SerialNo, EnrollmentNo, TimeIn, TimeOut, AttendanceStatus (Present/Absent), ActionDate, DoneBy

The question is, when I download Attendance Logs and populate them to ListView the columns I've (from the device) are:

SQN, EnrollNumber, VerifyMody, InOutMode, Date (Contains Date and Time value).

So, I'm planning to Download Attendance Logs, then Insert/update to EmployeeAttendance Table, my challenge is related how to make TimeIn, and TimeOut?

Let me clear it a little bit, When All employee make their attendance at the morning, then a User should download the Attendance Logs, When Attendance Logs are downloaded, I'm going to Insert EmployeeAttendance Table and match Date column of downloaded data and TimeIn column in EmployeeAttendance Table and set NULL to TimeOut - this is a TimeIn Transaction and Clear the Logs, and at the End of the day, a user should download Attendance Logs, then I'm going to update Date column of the downloaded Attendance Logs to TimeOut (Previously set to NULL) column of EmployeeAttendance Table of each Employee and Clear the Logs.

So, is this a better way to control the Attendance? Or I may encounter problems?

Suggest me a better way theoretically, and I'm more than happy to implement it if it's Ok.

Edit:

VerifyMode:
Pointer pointing to a long variable. The value is the verification mode of the received attendance record. The values are as follows:
Generally, 0: password verification, 1:fingerprint verification,2: card verification

InOutMode:
Pointer pointing to a long variable. The value is the AttState of the received attendance record. The values are as follows:
0—Check-In (default value) 1—Check-Out 2—Break-Out
3—Break-In 4—OT-In 5—OT-Out.

Ref: TFT SDK Manual

Comment: You may find it easier to download the data in it original format and then use SPs and/or SSIS to transform the data into your desired format.  This approach can help you spot capture errors, like bad reads, users forgetting to log in/out, etc.

Comment: Yes, I'm planning to do that (using SPs), but, is my approach is Ok to implement this functionality? the hardest part is how to make TimeIn and TimeOut with out data loss, since every time Attendance Log is downloaded, then cleared.

Comment: Yes you should be fine. Staging the data before calculating the in/out times will increase your options. Some data loss is unavoidable. The real world always throws up exceptions and unexpected event sequences. Your SP could  tag your final records with a marker for incomplete/missing data (time out missing etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyse the data from the Bio-metric system logs.

> SQN, EnrollNumber, VerifyMody, InOutMode, Date (Contains Date and Time
>   value).

Analyse what values are there in VerifyMody, InOutMode.
Does InOutMode provide any detail if its the first swipe or second or so on...
What will be the log if the user swipes twice.Which record will you consider then from the log.

These are the question you get when you analyse the raw data and you will get the idea on what kind of logic do you need to apply.

E.g. if the device logs all the swipes by the same user then you consider the first record as the in time and the last record of the day as out time.

Hope you get my point and this helps you.

Comment: VerifyMode:
Pointer pointing to a long variable. The value is the verification mode of the received attendance record. The values are as follows:
Generally, 0: password verification, 1:fingerprint verification,2: card verification

InOutMode:
Pointer pointing to a long variable. The value is the AttState of the received attendance record. The values are as follows:
0—Check-In (default value) 1—Check-Out 2—Break-Out
3—Break-In 4—OT-In 5—OT-Out.

Ref: TFT SDK Manual

Comment: other than the mannual do you have any data from usage?

Comment: Yes I've, but what I'm still searching is how to configure TimeIn and TimeOut at device level, or a better way to decide TimeIn and TimeOut at Database Level. Thank you for your help.